# XSLT: Copy all XML except where attribute contains value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

#### Goal

I'd like to copy all XML except where attribute value contains a specific character, in this case, `.`. Where `.` exists, remove the element that has that attribute & all its children. I'm pretty new to xslt and did some reading, but I cannot seem to find a way to grab the parent + all its children.

#### Current XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">

        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />

        </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="descendant-or-self::root/*/@name[contains(., '.')]" />
```

#### Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <complexType name="tableData2File">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="taskElement">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="source" type="tableData2File.source" />
                    <element name="parser" type="parser" />
                    <element name="target" type="node.uri" />
                </sequence>
                <attribute name="addNewColumns" type="minlength" use="optional" />                              
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <!-- 
    match idViolationsCount.test,
    then remove all its content
     -->
    <complexType name="idViolationsCount.test">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="tableTask">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="index" type="columnsNoAs" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="condition" type="stringWithRef" minOccurs="0" />
                    <element name="allowExpressions" type="boolWithRef" minOccurs="0" />
                </sequence>
                <attribute name="mode" type="mergeMode" use="required" />
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

</root>
```

#### Desired Output XML

```
<root>
    <complexType name="tableData2File">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="taskElement">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="source" type="tableData2File.source" />
                    <element name="parser" type="parser" />
                    <element name="target" type="node.uri" />
                </sequence>
                <attribute name="addNewColumns" type="minlength" use="optional" />                              
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <!-- no idViolationsCount.test! --> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like the right approach (an identity template, overridden for the thing you want to remove), but you can't use `descendant-or-self::` in a match pattern.  However, you don't need to, just

```
<xsl:template match="root/*[contains(@name, '.')]" />
```

should do the job.  Note that your original match pattern of `root/*/@name[contains(., '.')]` would match the `name` attribute node, not the element that hosts it, so you would end up removing the attribute but leaving the element intact.

You don't need to do anything special about the children of the removed element - this empty template will remove the whole element including its content, if you wanted to remove just this element but preserve its children then you'd need a different template

```
<xsl:template match="root/*[contains(@name, '.')]">
  <!-- don't output anything now, but keep processing children -->
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```